# Accessing schema properties from Mongoose methods

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

**usermodel.js**

```
var userSchema = mongoose.Schema({

    local            : {
        email        : String,
        password     : String,
    }
});

userSchema.methods.validPassword = function(password) {
    user=this; 
    return this.local.password; <---------------THIS LINE
};

module.exports = mongoose.model('User', userSchema);
```

So I call something in server.js

**server.js**

```
var User = require('./usermodel.js);

var objectUser = {
    email: "a2@a.com",
    password: "a222"
};

console.log(objectUser.User.validPassword());
```

Can it return **the actual email?**

**How can you access a property of a user from the database without using?**

```
db.find({email: "a2@a.com"}).....
```

Answer (score 0):

You can search through your database with an api call, so if I was trying to check a users email for a login post I would do something like this. This here is set up for a form request on any user trying to login to the application.

`signIn: function (req, res) {
      var $email  = req.body.email
      mongoDB.User.findOne({email: $email}, function(err, user){
        if(err){res.json(err)}
        // Check if a User exists
        if(user){
        // Do whatever you want to do with the users info. Typically you would do such things as verify passwords and what not.
          }
      })
    }`

Comment: Now if your asking how to access a users information from their info from the database. You would essentially capture their information once they are logged in, and then display their credentials like their email on the front end of the application.